# Can we create a real device model specific Emulator/Simulator in Android Studio like OPPO A37 Model without having real device

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation

We are facing some issues on a very specific device `OPPO A37` as reported by our customer. The app just closes after taking some action however all other devices are working fine for any such action.

Our development team doesn't have `OPPO A37` as real device and we want to create an **Emulator** for `OPPO A37`. Is there any way to create an Emulator for a specific device like `OPPO A37` in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t  think so is there any way to create some specific device in emulator using android studio. But You can https://www.genymotion.com/ this will allow to create some specific device emulator.

I don’t know it is proving OPPO devices's emulator or not but it have a lot of devices list.